# Existence of how many sets is asserted by the axiom of choice in this case?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Applying the axiom of choice to $\{\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{5,6\},\ldots\}$, does only one choice set necessarily exist, or all of the $2^{\aleph_0}$ I "could have" chosen?  Or something in between?  It seems if only one, then I didn't really have much of a choice; I just had to take what the universe gave me.  But letting them all exist has its own problems.

Comment: Axiom of choice (although unnecessary in this case) asserts that _at least one_ choice set exists. However, AC doesn't (immediately) tell you how many there are. In fact, it turns out that there _are_ $2^{\aleph_0}$ such sets.

Comment: What do you mean, "letting them all exist has its own problems"? It seems to be a necessary truth that ***they all exist***, axiom of choice or no axiom of choice.

Comment: bof - I agree it seems necessary.  However, if every model contains an uncountable number of these choice sets, then every model is uncountable.  Per Lowenheim-Skolem there have to be countable models if there are any models.  So letting all these sets exist in every model is equivalent to ZFC being inconsistent.  What do you think?

Comment: Every model $M$ contains something it calls $\Pi_{n\ge 0} \{2n+1, 2n+2\}$, the Cartesian product the family. It's the set of all possible choice functions for the family. The axioms of ZF guarantee its existence; AC guarantees that it's nonempty. Within $M$, its version of the product is uncountable, because $M$ contains no surjection to it from the integers. (Anyway, none from what $M$ calls the integers. Assume $M$ is a standard model, e.g. it's transitive, so its integers are the real thing.). If $M$ itself is countable, however, there is such a surjection, but it's *outside of $M$*.

Comment: @BrianO: What you're saying does not contradict what the asker said, though his/her "letting them all exist has its own problems" is an a bit weird way to say "they may not all exist in the model".

Comment: @BrianO: So in a countable model, most of the choice functions/choice sets which exist outside the model don't exist in the model.  But doesn't each one of these choice sets result from a specific application of the axiom of choice so that the axiom of choice is false if one of them is missing from the model?  I had a similar problem with the power set of the naturals being countable in countable models.  I guess this model business just goes over my head.

Comment: *"But doesn't each one of these choice sets result from a specific application of the axiom of choice so that the axiom of choice is false if one of them is missing from the model?"* No, not at all. AC says only: there exists a choice function. A model needs only one choice function per family. The choice functions that aren't in a model do not all "result from... an application of AC". It is true, though, that none of them has an absolute definition and provably exists from the other axioms of ZF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you don’t need the axiom of choice to get a choice function: just pick the smaller member of each pair. Various other choice functions are explicitly definable: we could just as well pick the larger member of each pair, for instance. Or we could pick the member that is divisible by $3$ if there is one, and the smaller one otherwise.

In general the axiom of choice gives you more than one choice function. Let $\{A_i:i\in I\}$ be a family of non-empty sets, and let $\varphi:I\to\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ be a choice function. For each $i\in I$ let

$$B_i=\begin{cases}
A_i,&\text{if }|A_i|=1\\
A_i\setminus\{\varphi(i)\},&\text{otherwise}\;;
\end{cases}$$

then the axiom of choice gives us a choice function $\psi:I\to\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$ for the family $\{B_i:i\in I\}$. This $\psi$ is clearly also a choice function for the original family, and it’s different from $\varphi$ unless every $A_i$ was a singleton. Eventually, once the appropriate cardinal arithmetic has been developed, one can prove that it gives us

$$\prod_{i\in I}|A_i|$$

choice functions.

Answer (score 3):

The axiom of choice asserts there exists *one* choice function. However, like the problem with many vermin and pests, we usually have that if there is one then there are many (unless, all sets are singletons).

Specifically for sets of natural numbers you don't need the axiom of choice in order to prove that there are continuum many choice functions.

But generally speaking, if you know that $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ admits a choice function, and say all the sets have at least two elements, then for every $a\in A_i$ there is a choice function such that $f(i)=a$. How? Simply fix one choice function, and change it on one coordinate at a time. This means that there are plenty of choice functions indeed.

Without the axiom of choice we can sometimes manufacture examples where there are a few choice functions, in the sense that the number of them is exactly what you'd get by one fixed choice function and finitely many changes to it. That's odd.

Comment: Even if you do have the axiom of choice, if you use it only once you get only $\#(A)$ many choice functions on $2^A$ for infinite $A$, one for each set of finite changes to the single choice function provided. Right?

Comment: @user21820: Yes, this method only gives you that many. But you can get clever and start "mixing" choice functions by choosing from smaller families and get more. Or just be a normal person and prove cardinal arithmetic works for infinite products as well, so you get the maximum number of choice functions. :-)

Comment: Hahaha I'm always intrigued with the question of the minimum number of times an axiom needs to be used to prove something, and conversely what can be proven if an axiom can only be used a certain number of times. =)

Comment: Well. If you only use it finitely many times in a proof, you can just fix a choice function from some very very very large family (e.g. all non-empty sets below a certain rank), and then you only appeal to it once. If you used choice infinitely many times, then your proof is not a standard proof anyway and you must be god.

Comment: Lol I must think more carefully about what I meant. There's this intuitive feeling sometimes that something needs to be used more than once. What happens when you use AC to define each item in a sequence? Is it always the case that any such construction can be done using only one use of AC (before constructing the sequence)? By "one use of AC" I do not allow extra universal quantification of AC (which would otherwise allow unlimited use just by using "forall x in { ... } ( AC holds for x )".

Comment: Well, it's an interesting question whether or not can one always make "predicative choices" or if one can find a statement provable in ZFC, but no proof with a single application of AC can be found. My money is on the latter. Not sure how you can find it, it's probably a matter of coding something into something else, and so on. :-)

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing about a reason to downvote, granted this reason is not "I don't like the user who wrote the answer". Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not me certainly, so let me compensate. I can only guess that the downvoter didn't really know what you were talking about, especially in the last paragraph.

Comment: Asaf, if each $X_i$ has size two and $\prod_i X_i$ is nonempty, do you know whether it can be Dedekind-finite?

Comment: @Andres: No, since in that case the union of the pairs is well-orderable (well, assuming the index set is well-orderable) and the cardinality of the product is its power set (proof: a choice function gives you exactly one remaining distinguished element from each pair, and thus defines a uniform linear ordering on all the pairs).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, so silly of me: I had *exactly* that argument in mind to see that it could not be $\aleph_0$ (and yes, I was thinking of a countable index set). OK, and when the index set $I$ is Dedekind-finite, the product has size $2^{|I|}$, which may also be Dedekind-finite.

Comment: @Andres: Yes, that is correct. But in any case, if the product is nonempty, might as well assume that $X_i=\{0,1\}$ for all $i$. What happens when we're talking about products of larger finite sets, that's far more interesting.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I figured :-) But should think a bit more about it before embarrassing myself again.